# Change of basis help turning a sub-matrix from complex to real

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, jordan-normal-form

I have the following matrix:

$$
\Lambda=\begin{bmatrix}
\Lambda_1 \\
 & \Lambda_2 \\
 & & \ddots \\
 & & & \Lambda_m
\end{bmatrix}\in\mathbb R^{n\times n}
$$

Where $\Lambda_1\in\mathbb C^{2\times 2}$ equals the following:

$$
\Lambda_1=\begin{bmatrix}
\sigma+j\omega & 0 \\
0 & \sigma-j\omega
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Note that $\Lambda$ is the Jordan decomposition of matrix $A\in\mathbb R^{n\times n}$ with respect to the basis $\{v,v^*,v_3,...,v_n\}$ where $v=x+jy\in\mathbb C^n$ and $v^*=x-jy\in\mathbb C^n$ are two eigenvectors of $A$ associated with $\lambda=\sigma+j\omega$ and $\lambda^*=\sigma-j\omega$ respectively.

**Question**: I need to find transformation matrix, $T$, into a new basis (specify what basis it is, too) in which:

$$
T\Lambda T^{-1}=\begin{bmatrix}
\widetilde\Lambda_1 \\
 & \Lambda_2 \\
 & & \ddots \\
 & & & \Lambda_m
\end{bmatrix}\in\mathbb R^{n\times n}
$$

Where $\widetilde\Lambda_1\in\mathbb R^{2\times 2}$.

The trouble is, I am unable to find this new basis, nor the transformation matrix for it. My current thinking is that the new basis should be:

$$
\left\{
\begin{bmatrix}
\sigma+j\omega \\ 0 \\ \vdots \\ 0
\end{bmatrix}\in\mathbb C^n,
\begin{bmatrix}
0 \\ \sigma-j\omega \\ \vdots \\ 0
\end{bmatrix}\in\mathbb C^n,v_3,...,v_n
\right\}
$$

Which would give $\widetilde A_1=\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0\\0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$, however at that point (assuming the basis is correct), I am unable to find the change of basis matrix... Thanks for helping me out with this!

Comment: Assuming that you mean $j^2 = -1$ and $\sigma, \omega$ real in $\Lambda_1,$ you have a matrix with trace $2 \sigma$ and determinant $\sigma^2 + \omega^2.$ Can you guess a matrix of reals with matching trace and determinant?

Comment: @WillJagy Yes, it's $$
\begin{bmatrix}
\sigma & -\omega \\
\omega & \sigma
\end{bmatrix} $$, what's the idea? Thanks for helping!

Comment: good. This is similar to your $\Lambda_1,$ call this one $A,$ there is a complex matrix $P$ with $P^{-1} A P = \lambda_1;$ uses eigenvalues, eigenvectors, but a certain amount of care and checking correctness. Off to grocery store

Comment: @WillJagy I think I got it, tell me if this is correct:

Basis: $\{\frac{j}{2}v-\frac{j}{2}v^*,\frac{1}{2}v+\frac{1}{2}v^*,v_3,...,v_n\}$

Transformation matrix:

$$
T=\begin{bmatrix}
P & 0 \\
0 & I
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Where $P=\begin{bmatrix}-j & j\\ 1 & 1\end{bmatrix}$ and $I$ is the identity matrix $\in\mathbb R^{(n-2)\times(n-2)}$